# Checking in baggage early with United Airlines at San Francisco

Tags: luggage, united-airlines, san-francisco, sfo

I've got like a 10 hour stopover in San Francisco (SFO) and I want to check out the city quickly. How early can I check in my luggage or are there any other solutions for the baggage problem?

Comment: What is the airline of the incoming flight? Is it an international or domestic flight? Are both flights on the same booking? In some cases, you should be able to check your luggage through to your final destination.

Comment: @jcaron: Airline is the same. Domestic incoming, international outgoing

Comment: Did you get separate tickets or something? Normally your bags would just be checked through.

Comment: @Michael: No, but apparently if you are switching from domestic to international, you have to grab your luggage

Comment: Really? That's ... very unusual. Which airline is making you do that?

Answer (score 5):

For a domestic arrival and transit, your baggage would be checked through to your final destination anyway, and it is not a concern.

For an international arrival and transit, which I believe is what you are concerned with, you will claim your baggage, walk it through Customs, and then follow the Connecting Flights sign to the baggage drop immediately outside the doors of the customs area. You can then leave the airport.